# В чем может быть причина вывода данной ошибки? На старых версиях php artisan migrate успешно производит

Tags: php, laravel

Начал изучать `laravel` с предыдущей версии, после обновления на 8.6 не могу выполнить `php artisan migration`, т.к. выдаёт ошибку:

```
"Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = adminka3 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
1.  C:\OpenServer\domains\my-lara.loc\adminka3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

2.   C:\OpenServer\domains\my-lara.loc\adminka3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=adminka3", "root", "root", [])
```

[image: Вывод ошибки php artisan migrate]

Это настройки `OpenServer` (пробовал менял на разные версии):
[image: Настройки OpenServer]

PDO установлен, т.к. на прошлой версии лары всё работало, мой `phpinfo()`:
[image: Вывод phpinfo()]

Ещё нашёл решение что нужно x64 apache, но это же противоречит тому что работало на более старой версии?
Стоит устанавливать `openserver` с возможностью переключиться на x64?

Намекните куда смотреть, чтобы я смог продолжить обучение лары?

Comment: Если вы связываетесь с MySQL, то почему загружаете драйвер MariaDB вместо него?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov ставил MySQL, аналогичная ошибка. я могу ошибаться, но это не одно и тоже?

Comment: В `php -m` есть pdo_mysql? У вас разные php скорее всего)

Answer (score 1):

Проверь путь к php в системной переменной PATH. Скорей всего он ведет на версию php, отличную от той, которая используется OpenServer. Если это так - просто замени на путь к нужной версии.

Также для laravel 8.* требуется php версии 7.3 и выше.

Comment: А это как вариант! Спасибо буду пробовать, о результате напишу позже